# EMGU EqualizeHist throws error on specific image resolutions

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

While carrying out EqualizeHist function invoked from EMGU, it throws the following error.

"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

This error is happening for the images only with the following resolutions. For all other resolutions it is working fine.

```
width = 1785 height = 1200
width = 1786 height = 1200
width = 1787 height = 1200
width = 1786 height = 1205
width = 1786 height = 1204
width = 1786 height = 1203
width = 1786 height = 1201
width = 1786 height = 1200
width = 1786 height = 1199
```

Following is the code

```
Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, Byte> imageCV = new Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, Byte>("file.jpg");
Emgu.CV.Image<Gray, byte> grayframe = imageCV.Convert<Gray, byte>();
grayframe._EqualizeHist();
```

For example, width = 1786 height = 1200 throws error, while width = 1786 height = 1202 doesn't. You can easily recreate this error by resizing any image to the above mentioned resolution and it will throw the error.

I checked the above resolutions in C++ opencv and it works fine there.

Kindly let me know what could be the problem behind this error.

Comment: Every figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: This issue was happening to me while I was using 64-bit opencv library in 32-bit project. Once I used the 32-bit library, the issue was solved.